# Pandas group by multiple columns, filter and take ratio of averages

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, filter, pandas-groupby

I would like to groupby a dataframe using two columns, then filter the results which has less than some threshold value and then take the ratio of the means.

Example:

```
grouped_df = df_test[["bool_column", "A", "B",
        "C", "filter_column"]].groupby(["filter_column", "bool_column"])
grouped_df.describe()
```

This gives me something like:

```
                   bool_column       A       B       C
filter_column

Name1                 True       <stats> <stats> <stats> [count = 4]
                      False      <stats> <stats> <stats> [count = 2]
Name2                 True       <stats> <stats> <stats> [count = 3]
                      False      <stats> <stats> <stats> [count = 1]
```

I now want to filter out those fields where count < 2. So I want:

```
                   bool_column       A       B       C
filter_column

Name1                 True       <stats> <stats> <stats> [count = 4]
                      False      <stats> <stats> <stats> [count = 2]
Name2                 True       <stats> <stats> <stats> [count = 3]
```

After this I want to take the ratio of means of columns `A`, `B` and `C`. That is for each filter column, I need

```
colA[True].mean / colb[False].mean
```

I couldn't get the filter to work anyway. I tried the following:

1. `grouped_df2 = grouped_df.filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)`
2. `grouped_df2 = grouped_df2.stack()`
3. `grouped_df = grouped_df.filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0)`

The following works to get the ratio:

```
df = grouped_df['A'].mean().unstack('bool_column')
df = df[(df[True] > 0) & (df[False] > 0)]
df['ratio'] = df[True] / df[False]
df = df.drop(columns=[True,False])
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

Comment: How do you want to calculate the ratio after removing some rows? E.g. in your example there is no False for Name2.

Comment: I would just ignore it, I do not need that in the output. @Shaido

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible solution, first aggregate both the mean and count of each group:

```
df = grouped_df.agg([np.mean, 'count'])
```

Then filter the rows where the count is too low:

```
df = df[df['A', 'count'] > 1]
```

Drop the unnecessary count columns and rename:

```
df = df.drop('count', axis=1, level=1)
df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0)
```

To calculate the mean, first unstack the `bool_column` and then add the new `ratio` column for each data column:

```
df = df.unstack()

for col in df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique():
    df[col, 'ratio'] = df[col, True] / df[col, False]
```

Finally, select only the `ratio` columns:

```
df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_level_values(1) == 'ratio']
```

Result:

```
                  A      B
  bool_column     ratio  ratio
filter_column       
            1       NaN    NaN
            2  0.857143  0.875
```